# dont go to next activity unless the entire box is fill

Tags: java, android, validation, onclick, android-edittext

I made an app for my use for calculating a string of values appear in an another activity. My app has 3 `editTexts` and one `button`. If we press button `calculate` with the input in edit text and calculated values will displayed in a second activity. I made it successfully but my problem is if the user is leave any of the boxes empty and press the button, the system will Force Close. To avoid this I made `editText` in graphical layout pre entered with a hint. But if the user accidentally presses button after editing the `editText` again system shows a Force Close.
I tried many `if else` methods but it does not work. Some one show me a correct way to check all `editText` boxes.

```
public class Screen1 extends Activity {

public static StringBuilder EXTRA_MESSAGE=null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.screen1);
    Button bu1= (Button)findViewById(R.id.bu);
    bu1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
                    @Override
        public void onClick(View message)
        {    int f1,f3,f4; 
            String vis;
             EditText t1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.a);
             EditText t3=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.c);
             EditText t4=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.d);
            String e1=t1.getText().toString();
            String e3= t3.getText().toString();
            String e4= t4.getText().toString(); 
f1 =Integer.parseInt(e1);
f4=Integer.parseInt(e4);
f3=Integer.parseInt(e3);
     StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for( float i= (float)0.1;i<=5;i=i+(float) .1)
    { 

    sb.append(String.format("%.1f", i)+" mcg = "+(f1*60*i*f4)/(f3*1000)+"\n");
    }
vis=sb.toString();
    Intent intent = new Intent(message.getContext(),Screen2.class);

     intent.putExtra("EXTRA_MESSAGE",vis);
startActivity(intent);
        }       

});     
}
}
```

Comment: Please mark this accepted. Help out all our reps. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I gather from your question, you're getting an error when `bu1` is clicked, and at least one of the EditTexts is empty. This is because you're calling `Integer.parseInt()` on an empty String. The following code will check if the boxes are empty, and show a Toast if any are. It will also show a Toast if the user enters anything that's not a valid number:

```
public class Screen1 extends Activity
{
    private static final String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "extra_msg";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.screen1);

        final EditText t1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.a);
        final EditText t3 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.c);
        final EditText t4 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.d);

        Button bu1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bu);
        bu1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {
                public void onClick(View message)
                {
                    int f1,f3,f4; 
                    String e1 = t1.getText().toString();
                    String e3 = t3.getText().toString();
                    String e4 = t4.getText().toString();

                    if (e1.equals("") || e3.equals("") || e4.equals(""))
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(Screen1.this, "Please enter all numbers.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        return;
                    }

                    try
                    {
                        f1 = Integer.parseInt(e1);
                        f4 = Integer.parseInt(e4);
                        f3 = Integer.parseInt(e3);

                        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                        for (float i = 0.1f; i <= 5; i = i + .1f)
                        { 
                            sb.append(String.format("%.1f", i) + " mcg = " + (f1 * 60 * i * f4) / (f3 * 1000) + "\n");
                        }

                        Intent intent = new Intent(Screen1.this, Screen2.class);
                        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, sb.toString());
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                    catch (NumberFormatException e)
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(Screen1.this, "Invalid numbers.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();                            
                    }
                }       
            }
        );     
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot i was trying to get a solusion for my problem for last few months this answer help me , thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

Using `[TextUtils][1]` check `isEmpty()` text inside your `onClick`:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
     EditText t1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.a);
     EditText t3=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.c);
     EditText t4=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.d);

     Button bu1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bu);
     bu1.setOnClickListener(this);
}    

@Override
public void onClick(View message){  
     boolean foundEmpty = false;

     if(TextUtils.isEmpty(t1.getText())) {
         foundEmpty = true;
         t1.setError("Please Enter a value");
     }

     if(TextUtils.isEmpty(t2.getText()){
        foundEmpty = true;
        t2.setError("Please Enter a value");
     }

     if(TextUtils.isEmpty(t3.getText()){
        foundEmpty = true;
        t3.setError("Please enter a value");
     }

     if(!foundEmpty){
         /* none of your text fields are empty */
         int f1, f3, f4; 

         f1 =Integer.parseInt(e1);
         f4=Integer.parseInt(e4);
         f3=Integer.parseInt(e3);

         final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
         for( float i= (float)0.1;i<=5;i=i+(float) .1) { 
               sb.append(String.format("%.1f", i)+
                    " mcg = "+
                    (f1*60*i*f4)/(f3*1000)+"\n");
         }

         final String vis = sb.toString();
         Intent intent = new Intent(message.getContext(), Screen2.class);
         intent.putExtra("EXTRA_MESSAGE", vis);
         startActivity(intent);
    }       
}
```

Comment: What are t1, t3, t4? They are not initialized at all.

Comment: @Binghammer, I forgot about this question, but I had meant to tell you that an empty EditText will return an empty String, not a null value. Also, there's a syntax error in your if conditional.